# Python 3: working with files

Tags: python, file-io, python-3.x

I'm reading in my textbook that a file object has a readlines method, which loads a whole file  into a list of strings:

```
>>> f = open('script1.py')
>>> lines = f.readlines()
>>> lines
```

**Result**:

```
['import sys\n', 'print(sys path)\n', 'x = 2\n', 'print(2**33)\n']
```

I always like to consult a documentation when I analyse what I read. But I met my Waterloo trying to find this in the documentation? Could you help me?

Comment: files API, binary strings etc... changed in v3. It is not uncommon to stick with Python v2.x...

Comment: Most of the time, *instead* of using `readlines`, you should just iterate over the file. I'd get a better textbook ;)

Answer (score 1):

The docs for [open()](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#open) describe what values and under what conditions it may return with links to their documentation. In particular `.readlines()` method is described in the docs for [common base class io.IOBase](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/io.html).

I use google or [the search field in the docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/) or `help(f.readlines)` (or an equivalent such as the automatic tooltip in bpython).

Answer (score 1):

`help(f)` or just `help(f.readlines)` will help you. However, `readlines()` is almost deprecated and not recommended, especially when the file is of large size.

If you want to iterate over the file, you can use:

```
for line in f: process(line)
```

If you want to handle the whole file, just use:

```
all_the_text = open('script1.py').read()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the official docs here:

http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files